# Simple multiple variable replace

Tags: database, command, stata

I want a simple way to replace the values of several variables (let's say varlist A) conditional on the values of other variables. In my case to every name of each variable in A there corresponds a modified name in B as folllows:

A (var1 var2 var3 ...)

B (_var1 _var2 _var3 ...)

So I would like to replace the value of `var1` by that of `_var1` if `var1` is missing

Answer (score 2):

Various ways; here is one.

```
  forval j = 1/3 { 
        replace var`j' = _var`j' if missing(var`j') 
  }
```

For a tutorial on such loops, see http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0005

(LATER) "My real problem is different...."

```
 foreach v in p503 p605 p201c {
     replace `v' = _`v' if missing(`v') 
 }
```

If you read the article I suggested you will learn that `forval` and `foreach` can take loops over various kinds of list.

Comment: The issue is that names are quite different like A(p503 p605 p201c) and B(_p503 _p605 _p201c) So there is no logical order on names.  What to do in that case?